# text animation specific pages css

Tags: html, css

Im trying to fade in my text across **specific** pages(not all). At the moment i have **one** stylesheet. My fade in is working correctly but i **dont** want it across all pages. I want to select it through a class or id.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-tranform">
    <div class="title-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2> Some dummy text </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>

.text-transform h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p{
  animation: fadein 2s;
-moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply don't use the .text-transform class on pages where you don't want the effect, what's the issue?

Comment: its doing it site wide

Comment: thats what i thought, just use it for the correct class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with your css selector.

```
.text-transform h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p{
//...
}
```

You're applying the style to every `h1` that is a descendent under `.text-transform`, but then all `h2`, `h3`, `h4` etc... The naive solution would be to use this

```
.text-transform h1,
.text-transform h2,
.text-transform h3,
.text-transform h4,
.text-transform h5,
.text-transform p{
//..
}
```

This isn't great code imo. Why don't you apply `.text-transform` directly on the element?

Comment: It is weird. Just put the class .text-transform on the element you want it on, don't do this descendent stuff. For example get rid of h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p, and then do it like this  <h2 class="text-transform"> Some dummy text </h1>

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way you're selecting in your css `.text-transform h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p`

This says do the effect on all h1 elements inside the `.text-transform` element. Also do the same effect on all h2, h3, h4, h5, and p elements, no matter what they're inside of. Your selection should be:

```
.text-transform h1,
.text-transform h2,
.text-transform h3,
.text-transform h4,
.text-transform h5,
.text-transform p
```